# How to approach a character's face?

Tags: modeling, object-mode

I noticed I am struggling with the same concept over and over.
I try to model a character inspired by a referenced photo, I finish with the general body of the character but when I reach modeling the different parts of its face (mouth and eyes) I have no idea how to do it properly.
Here is an example:

[image]

At first, I tried drawing the eyes on the texture, but I have concluded that texturing in Blender is not suited for this kind of stuff and more for well, the texture of the body rather than specific features of its face. When trying to draw on the texture it is never very precise and quite tedious.
I also have dabbled in sculpting but this too seems to be an approach that requires too much precision.

Is there a good rule of thumb for handling the eyes and the mouth in object mode?

Comment: There are several solutions for the faces, the eyes and mouth can be either pictures or volume, it really depend on what you prefer, maybe try to model them instead of using pictures. Also instead of sculpting begin with low-poly modeling, make sure to begin with as less faces as possible, but for the moment we can't see the wireframe, please show how it looks like

Comment: First you should probably decide if you want to model the face features, or if you only want them as texture. About modeling, try searching for "head topology" on your favorite search engine. It will give you an idea how to approach face features modeling.

Comment: @moonboots I have update the photo to show the wireframe of the face.
I assumed I must have it as a volume but I am open to any option that can show decent results without too much complications.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to begin with a UV sphere, nor to have so many faces at the beginning, nor to have separate parts (body/head/ears/etc), begin with the whole body and with as few faces as possible

Comment: I don't think there are any techniques specific to this. Seems to me this is just general modelling and texturing. Can this question really be answered?..

Comment: Dear Eule, maybe you could rephrase your question a bit. "trying to draw [...] and sculpting [...] is not precise and quite tedious" - However, many artists use these tools for exactly that purpose. If you can highlight your exact problems with either approach, we could maybe help you more effectively. (But I can confirm, the texturing tools of Blender are very bad. The sculpting brushes however are fairly good.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick breakdown to show you how you can model a character face

1. It's usually a good idea to start with a subdivided cube, so you'll get even topology
2. Roughly shape the model to get a similar overall shape as your reference. Here, I changed the mesh proportions and extruded the ears
3. If you don't have enough resolution for further detailing the model, apply another subdivision modifier
4. For the eyes, I made a selection of faces in the area where they should be and I did an inset on these faces to get a loop around the eyes (important step topology wise)
5. I did the same for the mouth, but deleted the inner faces after the inset operation
6. I then made the mouth bag, the teeth and tongue, the eyes (I just duplicated the eye socket faces and  and made the shape go outwards instead of inwards). I also slightly changed the topology around the eyes and mouth to add little bumps
7. Next I added simple shading, the scales on the skin and the iris(Btw this isn't the best way to make an eye, I recomend you check [how to make cartoon eyes using a lattice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4e-YdRIBUNw))
8. Final result

Hope that helps

[image]